# rake - running shell command returns error

Tags: ruby, rake

I am trying to run in Rake the following shell command:

```
sh "d='jps -l | grep jar | cut -d ' ' -f 1'; if [ -z \"$d\" ]; then :; else kill  \"$d\"; fi;"
```

However I get:

```
sh:  -f 1: not found
```

If I run it in linux shell it works fine.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted your question wrong earlier. This is what you want.

```
d='jps -l | grep jar | cut -d " " -f 1; if [ -z "$d" ]; then :; else kill "$d"; fi;'
system(d)
```

**OR**

If you want output of the command (which I guess you don't in this case)

```
output = `jps -l | grep jar | cut -d " " -f 1; if [ -z "$d" ]; then :; else kill "$d"; fi;`
```

Comment: sh "d=\"jps -l | grep jar | cut -d ' ' -f 1\"; if [ -z \"$d\" ]; then :; else kill  \"$d\"; fi;" does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your single quotes and quote the whole string:

```
d='jps -l | grep jar | cut -d \' \' -f 1; if [ -z "$d" ]; then :; else kill  "$d"; fi;'
```

Comment: It's not working. The command now is sh "d='jps -l | grep jar | cut -d \' \' -f 1; if [ -z \"$d\" ]; then :; else kill  \"$d\"; fi;'" and I get an error